# $\mathbb{E}[f_X (X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[f_Y (X)] $ true in general?

Tags: probability-theory

The above question is from a past probability theory PhD qualifying exam from my department. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are integer valued random variables, and $f_X (x) = \mathbb{P} (X = x)$, the question asks to show that the above inequality is true. The hint given is to explore the inequality between $\log x$ and $x-1$.

Is the above relationship true in general? I managed to come up with a counter example, but perhaps I misunderstand the question... Here's the counter example: Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables, such that $\mathbb{P} (X = 1) = 1/3, \mathbb{P} (X = 2) = 2/3, \mathbb{P} (X = 3) = 0,$ while $\mathbb{P} ( Y= 1) = \mathbb{P} (Y = 2) = 0, \mathbb{P} (Y = 3) = 1.$ Then, the inequality fails in this example.

Comment: The inequality is false and your example looks fine to me.

Comment: I think so too... Trivially, $\mathbb{E}[f_X (X)]  > 0$ in the countable setting, but given $X$, it's always possible to construct $Y$ such that $\mathbb{E}[f_Y (X)]  = 0$, is this counter example correct?

Comment: Yes. Your example is correct.